# How to allow a private server through internet in linux by using bastion server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

In AWS am having two server's bastion and private. I tried to give internet access to private server through bastion. So what i have to do for that.
Please help me on this.
Thanks,
Gurumahesh N.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have a NAT gateway for access to the internet from private subnets.

Make sure to have an internet gateway attached to your VPC. Add a nat gateway into the proper availability zone. Then update your private route table to point to that NAT gateway.